# Select from two tables to find vat rate based on effective date

Tags: sql, mysql, join, aggregate-functions

I have this two tables:

```
mysql> desc vat_rates;
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| rate_id     | varchar(5)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name        | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| type        | enum('O','I') | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| default     | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | 0       |       |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc vat_rates_details;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| rate_id     | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| effect_date | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| rate        | float       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need a query that gives me vat_rates.name, vat_rates.rate_id, vat_rates_details.rate WHERE the effect_date is MAX() but <= than now().

Simplifying, I need to select all vat_rates with rate field being the last date based on effect_date but not in the future.

Example with data:

**vat_rates:**
rate_id = 'L9'
name = 'MyVatName'
type = 'O'
default = 1

**vat_rates_details** (line 1):
rate_id = 'L9'
effect_date = '2000-01-01'
rate = 20

**vat_rates_details** (line 2):
rate_id = 'L9'
effect_date = '2010-06-01'
rate = 19

**vat_rates_details** (line 3):
rate_id = 'L9'
effect_date = '2010-07-01'
rate = 21

The expected result:

```
+-------------+-------------+------+
| rate_id     | name        | rate |
+-------------+-------------+------+
| L9          | MyVatName   | 19   |
+-------------+-------------+------+
```

Thanks for your time :)

**EDIT:** Expected rate is 19 not 20. Tks Justin.

Comment: aren't you expecting a rate of 19 as opposed to 20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select rd.rate_id, r.name, rd.rate
from (
    select rate_id, max(effect_date) as MaxEffectDate
    from vat_rates_details
    where effect_date < now()
    group by rate_id
) rdm
inner join  vat_rates_details rd on rdm.rate_id = rd.rate_id and rdm.MaxEffectDate = rd.effect_date
inner join vat_rates r on rd.rate_id = r.rate_id
```

Comment: if you add rd.rate to the first part of the select, this will return your desired results

Answer (score 0):

Other possible methods:

```
SELECT
    VR.name,
    VR.rate_id,
    VRD1.rate
FROM
    Vat_Rates VR
INNER JOIN Vat_Rate_Details VRD1 ON
    VRD1.rate_id = VR.rate_id AND
    VRD1.effect_date < NOW()        -- Is this the correct syntax for mySQL?
LEFT OUTER JOIN Vat_Rate_Details VRD2 ON
    VRD2.rate_id = VR.rate_id AND
    VRD2.effect_date < NOW() AND
    VRD2.effect_date > VRD1.effect_date
```

---

```
SELECT
    VR.name,
    VR.rate_id,
    VRD1.rate
FROM
    Vat_Rates VR
INNER JOIN Vat_Rate_Details VRD1 ON
    VRD1.rate_id = VR.rate_id AND
    VRD1.effect_date < NOW()
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Vat_Rate_Details VRD2
    WHERE
        VRD2.rate_id = VR.rate_id AND
        VRD2.effect_date < NOW() AND
        VRD2.effect_date > VRD1.effect_date
)
```